# Invoke Skype for Business from Web Chat control

Tags: web, botframework, skype-for-business, azure-bot-service

A button like below will open up a contact in Skype for Business. We have a Web Chat bot hosted on Azure bot Service. I would like to utilize the buttons present in the Web Chat control to invoke Skype for Business contacts in a similar way. But I'm not able to specify the href properly and this usually brings up the domain at the end of contact in browser instead of the pop up for SfB. Is there any smart workaround for this?

I had thought of this alternate option of redirecting the user to a web page with a button which can bring up SfB, but that's not a very good user experience.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Help Desk</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="sip:helpdesk.im@microsoft.com" width="550">Contact Help Desk Team on Skype for Business</button>
```

Comment: Which SDK are you planning on using and which version?

Comment: Am on v4 Python SDK. The SDK is still in preview, but most things work without any issues. The issue seems to be more in the way anchor tags are handled rather than the SDK.

Comment: You wouldn't use an anchor tag to achieve this in Bot Framework. Rather, you could instantiate a hero card with a button that has a CardAction assigned to it. The CardAction has an '.openUrl' method which you would give the value of 'sip:helpdesk.im@microsoft.com'. When the button is clicked in the bot it will open a browser window that would then make a request to start a Skype conversation in the Skype app.